# My code behaves differently in debug vs released/distributed mode - how can I test this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app which behaves differntly in debug mode vs when distributed.

How can I install a distrbuted equivalent version and still kind of debug it with xcode ?

Comment: Different in what way?

Comment: for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714255/why-does-this-code-crash-on-the-distributed-app-but-work-in-the-debugger

Comment: Have you examined the crash report from the distributed device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This different "behavior" has been seen in the past. Is given by "Optmization Level" setting. Debug version is set to None [-O0], while the Release version is set to Fastest, Smallest [-Os].

So... set the same in Debug mode (fastest... )

You can check also this 
[iPhone App floating point calculations when released to the app store.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210621/iphone-app-floating-point-calculations-when-released-to-the-app-store)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger will catch signals for you (so you can, you know, debug them). If you run the same code on a device without the debugger being attached, you will see the same behavior when exceptions are thrown, or signals raised.